# Field value returns null(MVC 4 file upload)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a problem in my file upload where one of the field(DocumentDepartment) value returns null, whilst all other field information is saved.

Please Help

I have the following code for my model:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentDepartment { get; set; }
    public byte[] DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

Code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase document)
{
    // verify user selected a file
    if (document != null && document.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //Get file information
        var documentName = Path.GetFileName(document.FileName);
        var contentLength = document.ContentLength;
        var contenttype = document.ContentType;
        var datadept = DocumentDepartment;

        //Get the file data
        byte[] data = new byte[] { };
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(document.InputStream))
        {
            data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(document.ContentLength);
        }

        //Save to the database
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.DocumentDepartment = datadept;
        doc.DocumentName = documentName;
        doc.DocumentType = data;

        //show success....
        db.Document.Add(doc);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewData["message"] = document.FileName + "has been saved.";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    return View(document);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are getting the value for datadept? As you only have one posted file arriving at the controller.  var datadept = DocumentDepartment; ???? where does this value get initialised from?

Comment: that is where my problem is , i tried using document.DepartmentType but it says the httppostedbasefile does not have a definition for it

Answer (score 0):

OK I think you do not understand the way that MVC and HTML forms work. If you receive an HttpPostedFile it is merely a wrapper for the binary data received. You will need to de-serialize the file from what is a stream of bytes into the typed object that you originally created.

Do you have serialization / de-serialization functions for your object?

If not consider looking into reading and writing typed objects to streams here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx